# Проблема создания двух версий формы для различных устройств при адаптивном дизайне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется изначально неадаптивная форма (корзина покупателя), имеющая табличную верстку `table`, каждый элемент ввода/показа имеет `name` вида `имяКолонки_НомерСтроки`.

Нужно сделать адаптивный дизайн формы. Новый дизайн для десктопов уже сделан, проблема заключается в создании мобильного дизайна: он полностью отличается от десктопного и не табличный.

Логично создать отдельную форму  и управлять скрытием/показом с помощью `hidden-xs`/`hidden-sm`.

Такого я никогда не делал и не знаю, как правильно реализовать привязку JS к двум формам/именование элементов формы и так далее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы уже решили разделить реализацию корзины на 2 части (десктоп/мобильная), то я бы сделал какую-то bool переменную (isMobile) в js, которая бы контролировала бы форму (перенаправляла бы поток управления в зависимости от типа устройства).

В CSS использовал бы media-query для скрытия/показа нужной формы на нужном устройстве ( ну а использование хидена от бустрапа или своего кода на js это уже ваше решение).

Comment: ОК, я завтра покажу эскиз, чтобы мы могли убедиться, что разделение - верное решение.

Comment: Если внутри старой формы имелись `div` элементы с аттрибутами `name`, которые использовались в селекторах, то их *нужно* заменить на `data-name`. И, кроме того, `id` нужно поменять на `name`

Comment: Ищется надежный способ определения, какой именно `div` или `DOM` - контейнер другого вида показывается сейчас.

Comment: @hellboy несовсем вас понял, что вы имеете ввиду. В этом плане надежней чем id нет ничего, но тогда придется много пилить правил для реакции на конкретном типе устройств. Я все таки предложил бы перепилить и десктоп и мобильную версию корзины на один лад. С помощью bootstrap это довольно быстро делается + не нужно много писать mediaquery т.к. в бутстрапе уже почти все готовое.

Comment: > Я все таки предложил бы перепилить и десктоп и мобильную версию корзины на один лад

Я не думаю, что это возможно. В десктопной версии у меня много колонок и на мобильной версии оно выглядело бы ужасно

Кроме того у меня уже есть готовый дизайн мобильной корзины. И выглядит она совсем по другому.

Comment: @hellboy а отталкиваться mobile first подход можноа? Ну т.е. раз у вас есть макет для мобильных телефонов, то вам его немного доработать (под соответсвующий масштаб и все такое). Можно конечно при наличии сервера, вообще сформировать 2 разные страницы (ну или тэмплэйты именно для корзины) и добавить реакцию на смену устройства. Второй вариант (неэфективен) - с помощью скрипта перекраивать html под нужное устройство (т.е. добавление/исправление/удаление нужных элементов в dom десктопной версии, чтобы привести её к мобильному виду.

Answer (score 0):

Все таки мы выбрали неправильный подход.

Необходимо сначала провести рефакторинг кода, а именно перенос логики построения вида из `Smarty` шаблона на клиента, используя простейший `MVVVM` - фреймворк. Далее необходимо выделить логику управления видом в один `ViewModel`.

[В `ko` один `ViewModel` можно привязать к разным `View`](http://jsfiddle.net/9abgxn8k/).

И уж далее смотреть, а нужен ли для мобильных ус-в отдельный `View` или автоматически преобразуемые `таблицы` `table` в `li`самого фреймворка `Oxid`  достаточны.

Без этого рефакторинга (в первом параграфе) вряд ли удастся создавать 2 вида в смысле `responsive` верстки.